# What is the attribute for a uicontrol object equivalent to deprecated uititle method

Tags: user-interface, scilab

I want to pretty much replicate the GUI implemented [here](https://wiki.scilab.org/howto/guicontrol):

and here is what I have got so far:

```
// first create the GUI panel
figw = 220; 
figh = 160;
close(1)
f = figure(1, "position", [0 0 figw figh]);
//PUSH TO STOP
hstop = uicontrol(f, "style", "pushbutton", "Min", 0, "Max", 1, "string", " STOP",..
    "position", [10 10 61 50], "callback", "infiniteloop=%F");
// TRIGGERED MODE
htrig = uicontrol(f, "style", "radiobutton", "Min", 0, "Max", 1, "string", "free/trig", "value", 0,..
    "position", [80 10 20 20]);
//httrig=uititle(htrig,"free/trig","r")
// BINNING x2
hbin = uicontrol(f, "style", "radiobutton", "Min", 0, "Max", 1, "value", 0,..
    "position", [80 40 20 20]);
//htbin=uititle(hbin,"bin x2","r")
// GREYSCALE
hbri = uicontrol("style", "slider", "Min", 1, "Max", 255, "value", 128,..
    "position", [10 70 200 20]);
//htbri=uititle(hbri,"greyscale")
// EXPOSURE (only for untriggered)
hexp = uicontrol("style", "slider", "Min", 1, "Max", 1200, "value", 40,..
    "position", [10 120 200 20]);
//htexp=uititle(hexp,"exposure time")
```

my main issue at this moment is that I can't find the equivalent attribute / property for the `uicontrol` objects which corresponds to the deprecated `uititle` method.

I could indeed use textboxes and find a workaround but that's not the ideal solution given all the positioning headaches. I was wondering if there is still such an attribute which accepts a stering and the put in the described position like `r`, `t`, `l` and `b`? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The famous `uititle` from Enrico Segre (emeritus Scilab contributor) could reborn like this, thanks to new layout features of uicontrols:

```
function t=uititle(h,text)
    pos = h.Position;
    pos(4)=pos(4)*2;
    f = uicontrol("style","frame","position",pos,"layout","grid")
    lay_opt = createLayoutOptions("grid", [2,1])
    set(f,"layout_options",lay_opt);
    c = createConstraints("grid");
    h.parent = f;
    t=uicontrol(f,"style","text","string",text,"horizontalalignment","center",...
                "constraints",c);
endfunction

clf
sl=uicontrol("style","slider","position",[10 10 200 20])
uititle(sl,"a slider")
```

Comment: It allows quite nice things like `sl.callback="t.string=string(sl.Value)"`

Comment: Dear Stéphane, Thanks for the kind and clever respond. what a coincidence, Enrico Segre is who initiated the Serial Toolbox which I'm working on  So to be clear this method or anything similar to this does not exists by default? I tried modifying your code to include the relative position option too, please see the current code [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/4076d4bb629577529b7fc9b778e65534). However I get the error `Undefined variable: lay_opt`

Comment: ok figured out that you have forgotten to define `lay_opt` probaby in your example it should be `lay_opt = createLayoutOptions("grid", [2,1])`. I updated [the gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/4076d4bb629577529b7fc9b778e65534) to incorporate this issue. However there are two issues: first width / height of the textbox is not necessarily twice the original uicontrol object. secondly I can't control to put the text exactly on left / right / top / bottom.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing peace of code, I have edited my answer. The size of the textbox is not defined a priori. What really matters is the size of the frame which will contain the two uicontrol. To control the position you have to play with the dimensions of the grid, `[2,1]` or `[1,2]` and with the order the two child widgets are packed, i.e. the two lines `h.parent=f` and `t=uicontrol...` should be swapped if necessary. You can also try to use the `gridbag`layout.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I decided to start collecting Scilab GUI examples and documentation. I will create a GitHub repo and will send it to you.

Comment: I added an `if statement` to take care of the `h` and `t` order. the only issue is now that the text odes not necessarily fit in the specified width.